# Given a dataset, how does one know whether there’s (statistical) noise on a set of measurements or not?

Tags: regression, noise

Just out of curiosity, I’m looking at linear regression and there are of course cases where the measurements of the response variable are not noisy(say in the case of a simulator). But in general how does one know if there’s noise on a set measurements or not? Is this just something we assume in the abscence of evidence to the contrary?

Comment: What is “statistical” noise?

Comment: @Dave used it to specify that I don’t mean noise in the physical sense unless said physical noise has resulted in noisy measurements

Comment: Then what is physical noise? Literal sonic noise like how people occasionally describe music they don’t like?

Answer (score 3):

Given a dataset (with no other information), you can never prove or know that a set of measurements include "noise" where noise is defined as a random process governed by a probability distribution.  What is perceived as noise could possibly be a signal of an unknown cause.

However, you can check assumptions about a signal that you perceive as noise to determine if it is effectively noise for your analysis.  In simple linear regression, $Y = \beta X + \epsilon$.

$\epsilon$ can be assumed to be noise if it follows a normal distribution $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and if the distribution of $\epsilon$ is statistically independent of the regressors.

In cryptography, there are also multiple tests of randomness that get applied to potential random number streams to determine if they are sufficiently random.  I don't normally see this type of thing in statistics / data science though.  See [this](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-22/rev-1a/final) from NIST.